# Obtener datos de una fila seleccionada

Tags: c#, windows-forms, devexpress

Estoy trabajando con **GridControl de DevExpress** para Windows Forms, lo que deseo es obtener datos de ciertas row, no se como hacerlo.

En DataGridView de Windows Forms lo hago de la siguiente manera

```
if (dgvCategoria.Rows.Count > 0)
            Helper.IdRow = Convert.ToInt32(dgvCategoria.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utiliza el método [GetFocusedRowCellValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetFocusedRowCellValuetopic(vb2Cmw)), así:

```
Helper.IdRow = Convert.ToInt32(GridControl1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("miColumna"));
```

Comment: Hola jachguate, probe con el nombre de la columna y no devuelve nada mas bien me da error de referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto y probe poniendole el FieldName y si funciono `Utilidades.RowId = gridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Id").ToString();`

Comment: jachguate, ¿Por que al control se le puede poner un nombre como gcPersona, pero el que tiene las propiedades del control es gridView1?, es como si fueran dos controles en uno?

Comment: No dos controles en uno, sino dos separados. El [GridControl](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraGridGridControltopic) es un contenedor de Vistas, que pueden ser de varias clases. Dale una mirada al tema [Views and Levels](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3462) para aclararte un poco.

Comment: jachguate, gracias por la información, la revisare ya que estoy usando DevExpress en el trabajo y ando perdido con las grillas.